# Haskell: Convert String representation of Integer List of Lists to Integer List of Lists

Tags: haskell, types

I have a file that contains a list of lists,

namely `[[39, 40, 1], [-39, -40, 1], [-39, 40, -1], [1, 41, 2], [-1, -41, 2], [-1, 41, -2], [2, 42, 3], [-2, -42, 3], [-2, 42, -3], [3, 43, 4], [-3, -43, 4], [-3, 43, -4], [4, 44, 5], [-4, -44, 5], [-4, 44, -5], [5, 45, 6], [-5, -45, 6], [-5, 45, -6], [6, 46, 7], [-6, -46, 7], [6, -46, -7], [7, 47, 8], [-7, -47, 8], [7, -47, -8], [-7, 47, -8], [8, 48, 9], [8, -48, -9], [-8, 48, -9], [9, 49, 10], [-9, -49, 10], [9, -49, -10], [-9, 49, -10], [10, 50, 11], [10, -50, -11], [-10, 50, -11], [11, 51, 12], [-11, -51, 12], [11, -51, -12], [-11, 51, -12], [-12, -52, 13], [12, -52, -13], [-12, 52, -13], [-13, -53, 14], [13, -53, -14], [-13, 53, -14], [14, 54, 15], [-14, -54, 15], [14, -54, -15], [-14, 54, -15], [-15, -55, 16], [15, -55, -16], [-15, 55, -16], [16, 56, 17], [-16, -56, 17], [16, -56, -17], [-16, 56, -17], [17, 57, 18], [-17, -57, 18], [-17, 57, -18], [18, 58, 19], [-18, -58, 19], [18, -58, -19], [-18, 58, -19], [19, 59, 60], [-19, -59, 60], [-19, 59, -60], [20, 59, 60], [-20, -59, 60], [20, -59, -60], [-20, 59, -60], [21, 58, 20], [-21, -58, 20], [21, -58, -20], [-21, 58, -20], [22, 57, 21], [-22, -57, 21], [22, -57, -21], [-22, 57, -21], [23, 56, 22], [23, -56, -22], [-23, 56, -22], [24, 55, 23], [-24, -55, 23], [24, -55, -23], [-24, 55, -23], [-25, -54, 24], [25, -54, -24], [-25, 54, -24], [26, 53, 25], [-26, -53, 25], [26, -53, -25], [-26, 53, -25], [27, 52, 26], [-27, -52, 26], [27, -52, -26], [-27, 52, -26], [28, 51, 27], [-28, -51, 27], [-28, 51, -27], [29, 50, 28], [-29, -50, 28], [29, -50, -28], [-29, 50, -28], [30, 49, 29], [-30, -49, 29], [30, -49,-29], [-30, 49, -29], [31, 48, 30], [-31, -48, 30], [31, -48, -30], [-31, 48, -30], [32, 47, 31], [-32, -47, 31], [32, -47, -31], [-32, 47, -31], [33, 46, 32], [33, -46, -32], [-33, 46, -32], [34, 45, 33], [-34, -45, 33], [34, -45, -33], [-34, 45, -33], [35, 44, 34], [-35, -44, 34], [35, -44, -34], [-35, 44, -34],[36, 43, 35], [-36, -43, 35], [-36, 43, -35], [37, 42, 36], [-37, -42, 36], [37, -42, -36], [-37, 42, -36], [38, 41, 37], [-38, -41, 37], [38, -41, -37], [39, 40, -38], [-39, -40, -38], [39, -40, 38], [-39, 40, 38]]`

I have figured out how to import the file but am having trouble converting it from a String -> [[Int]].

How would I go about do so?

Comment: What you are asking and how far you have gotten is unclear.  If you have "imported" this file then you shouldn't have a string.  1. What does the file look like exactly?  2. How are you importing it?  I suspect you have a file with exactly the above quoted data and you haven't imported it but instead read it a la `readFile` or similar - hence my question.

Comment: then I may not have even imported(read) the file correctly. the file contains exactly whats written.

Comment: Consider saving your data in another format like json.

Comment: to give some background, this problem i am having is for a stupid class where I need to solve the SAT (google it), I've already written a solution but am having a problem finding documentation on getting an ENTIRE (not line by line)file, into a string and converting it into the intended type.

I don't care about JSON because in a week i won't care about this assignment, etc etc.

Comment: It's unfortunate that you have such a negative view of a problem on SAT solvers - they are simply amazing and can help you solve really complex problems so quickly you'd feel like a wizard.  Things like breaking encryption algorithms, proving functions correct, detecting deadlocks, isolating bad sensors in self-driving cars, solving sudoko, etc etc. Regardless, if you decide to flesh out the question as mentioned above then you still might find help.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [read](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:read) or [readMaybe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe) function.

For example,

```
b :: [[Int]]
b = read "[[3, 4], [4, -5]]"
```